# el.minLength - Safari - camelCase не работает

Tags: javascript, кроссбраузерность

Проблема в следующем в chome el.minLength - работает, в Safari пишет undefined. Подскажите.

//html

```
 <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="auth-box__input" name="user_password" minlength="4" required>
```

//jscript

```
var user_password = document.getElementsByName('user_password')[0];
console.log(user_password.minLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нету его, этого вашего minLength в сафари.
[**Не сделали его там.**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью dataset:

//html

```
 <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="auth-box__input" name="user_password" minlength="4" data-length='4' required>
```

//js

```
var user_password = document.getElementsByName('user_password')[0];
console.log(user_password.dataset.length)
```